# How do Gaudiya Vaishnavas justify their strict adherence to ahimsa, vegetarianism, etc. when Krishna himself didn't advocate these?

Tags: krishna, food, gaudiya-vaishnavism, non-vegetarian, ahimsa

Gaudiya Vaishnavas claim that they follow the supreme Godhead Krishna. However, I have a few confusions.

First, as we know from the Mahabharata, that Krishna never told Arjuna to chant his name all the time. He never told him to have bead bags (Japa Mala). On the contrary, he instructed him to do his duty, which is the duty of a Kshatriya.

Second, Gaudiya Vaishnavas instruct their devotees to follow non-violence. However, Krishna never preached non-violence. From Mahabharata, we know that he was a very pragmatic person. When killing is necessary, he said go ahead.

Third, Gaudiya Vaishnavas instruct their devotees to have vegetarian food. But Krishna himself was non-vegetarian, as it was typical for any Kshatriya.

These discrepancies intrigue me.

How do Gaudiya Vaishnavas justify these practices when it would seem Krishna himself didn't follow/advocate them?

Comment: Gaudiya Vaishnavas are not the only ones who do japa, practice ahimsa, and eat strictly vegetarian food.

Comment: You tell your child not to play with fire. But you yourself strike a matchstick everyday. How do you justify your preachings when you yourself don't follow them ?

Answer (score 2):

I will try to clear your confusions line by line.

> Gaudiya Vaishnavas claim that they follow the supreme Godhead Krishna
> They don't, They follow instructions of Krishna in Gita.

1. Krishna indeed said chanting of names is a sacrifice and one must always think about him while doing one's duty.

> Amongst chants know me to be the repetition of the Holy Name(BG 10.25)
>
> Arjuna, you should always think of Me in the form of Kṛṣṇa and at the
> same time carry out your prescribed duty of fighting. With your
> activities dedicated to Me and your mind and intelligence fixed on Me,
> you will attain Me without doubt.(BG 8.7)
>
> Always think of Me, become My devotee, worship Me and offer your
> homage unto Me. Thus you will come to Me without fail. I promise you
> this because you are My very dear friend.(BG 18.65)

2. Krishna indeed preached non violence as Dharma and asked Arjuna to fight war in "Yoga"

> **Nonviolence**; truthfulness; freedom from anger...these transcendental qualities, O son of Bharata, belong to godly men
> endowed with divine nature.(BG 16.1–3)
>
> Do thou fight for the sake of fighting, without considering happiness
> or distress, loss or gain, victory or defeat – and by so doing you
> shall never incur sin(BG 2.38)
>
> Perform your duty equipoised, O Arjuna, abandoning all attachment to
> success or failure. Such equanimity is called yoga.(BG 2.48)
>
> **The spirit soul bewildered by the influence of false ego thinks himself the doer of activities** that are in actuality carried out by
> the three modes of material nature.(BG 3.27)
>
> **Those who see action in inaction and inaction in action are truly wise amongst humans.** Although performing all kinds of actions, they
> are yogis and masters of all their actions.(BG 4.18)

3. Foods are recomemnded based on Sattvika Rajasika and Tamasika elements. Ksatriyas indeed have Sattva and Rajo Gunas.

> Persons in the mode of goodness prefer foods that promote the life
> span, and increase virtue, strength, health, happiness, and
> satisfaction. Such foods are juicy, succulent, nourishing, and
> naturally tasteful. Foods that are too bitter, too sour, salty, very
> hot, pungent, dry, and chiliful, are dear to persons in the mode of
> passion. Such foods produce pain, grief, and disease. (BG 17.8-9)